# Conditional formatting depending on cell content (combination of a cell reference followed by specific text string)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have a range of cells. I want to format any of the cells in the range that contain a certain text string.

The problem is, the text string is constructed in 2 parts. The first part is a reference to another cell which can contain different text strings (the cell is actually referencing another cell, which is a drop down list with several choices). The second part is an actual defined text string.

In my example, cell `G2` contains the string `"REFERENCED CELL &"`.

In the range `B2:B11`, my formula is:

```
=IF(AND($E$2>=1,$E$2<=10),$G$2&" TEXT STRING 1",IF(AND($E$2>=11,$E$2<=20),$G$2&" TEXT STRING 2",""))
```

So:

- If cell `E2` contains a value that is between 1 and 10, then the cells in the range will contain the text string in cell `G2` followed by the text string `" TEXT STRING 1"`.
- If cell `E2` contains a value that is between 11 and 20, then the cells in the range will contain the text string in cell `G2` followed by the text string `" TEXT STRING 2"`.

I want to format this range differently for each of these outcomes.

- If the resulting string is `"REFERENCED CELL & TEXT STRING 1"` then the cell will be red.
- If the resulting string is `"REFERENCED CELL & TEXT STRING 2"` then the cell will be green.

How can I perform conditional formatting on a cell when its value is created in this way?

Comment: since " text string 1" and " text string 2" are defined constants, you could just do a search or countif formula for those text strings.  It would be two different conditional format rules, one for " text string 1" which would format red, and one for " text string 2" which would format green.  Give it a try and get back to us with any problems you run into.

Comment: SOLVED:

`=$B$2=$G$2&" TEXT STRING 1"`

and

`=$B$2=$G$2&" TEXT STRING 2"`

I tried so many things that looked so similar to this but wasn't quite right. I knew it would be something simple.

Thank you for your suggestion though ScottJShea. Much appreciated.

I probably should have mentioned that I needed to apply several different formats depending on which of the options is chosen from the drop down list. I've got it now. Hope this is of use to others in future.

Comment: Please post this as an answer, not a comment. Then accept your own answer. Also if you want to post an image but don't yet have enough reputation, then upload it to e.g. imgur.com and link to it here. A privileged user will probably paste it in for you later. Finally, please just get to the point when you write questions. No need for greetings, chattiness etc. The StackOverflow community appreciates brevity.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach:

[image: SO25373883 example]

where the two rules are (assuming integers):

Green `=AND(E$2>10,E$2<21)`
Red `=AND(E$2>0,E$2<11)`

Answer (score 0):

This solved the issue: `=$B$2=$G$2&" TEXT STRING 1"` and `=$B$2=$G$2&" TEXT STRING 2"`